# Getting DataGrid to Change Selected Item Selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

When I select an item in the DataGrid it seems that I cannot change the selection. I could click on another row but it will not do anything. I know this because when the action SelectionChanged happens for this datagrid full of customers I have a pop up box come up showing there name. The name is always the same. Here is the C# code

```
priavate void dataGridCustomers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs)
{
    Customer selectedCustomer = (Customer) dataGridCustomers.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedCustomer.FirstName);
}
```

I would like it so that every time I select a row, that is the selected item

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the definition below, I think you are trying to reference the selected item before it has actually been set.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this should do the trick:

```
private void dataGridCustomers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.AddedItems.Length > 0)
    {
        Customer selectedCustomer = (Customer) args.AddedItems[0];
        MessageBox.Show(selectedCustomer.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it says the selected item is null, why would that be?

Comment: SelectedItem is the item that is selected on the grid. On this event handler, the SelectedItem is only set after the sectionChanged event is executed. So if initially there was no SelectedItem (null) and you tried to check it in the method above, it would be null because it has not yet been set.

Comment: That's why you need to use the args.AddedItems - these are the items that will be added to the selection after the event handler (SelectionChanged) is fired

Comment: Now there is a lag whenever I select the second item